# Mix value of a cell with each value of other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please forgive me if this sounds stupid, I have 0 excel experience under my belt but I am trying to help a friend out with his file.

I am wondering if it is possible to mix(concatenate or other type) the value of A1 with all the values of B column and C column. Example:

- A Apple, Pear, Grape
- B Red, Yellow, Blue
- C Large, Medium, Small

Desired output:

Column D output: Apple Red Large, Apple Red Medium, Apple Red Small, Apple Yellow Large, Apple Yellow Medium, Apple Yellow Small, Pear Red Large, Pear Red Medium Etc.

I am looking to combine the values from A column with each of the values from B and C column as shown above. Is it possible or am I just complicating things ?

Thank you in advance for your time,
Dan

Comment: If `VBA` is allowed, add the `vba` tag by using `Edit tags` below your post.

Comment: I closed the question with a duplicate that will forward OP to all relevant previous similar questions needed to know how to solve this using formulae.

Answer (score 0):

=CONCAT(B6," ",C6," ",D6)